# Need equation to find half step value in SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: math, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

Ok, my math is a bit rusty and I feel like this should be an easy problem, but yet I am here.

For SimpleAudioEngine in Cocos2d, there is a pitch argument.  It is defined as follows:

> 1.0 is original pitch
>
> 0.5 is one octave (12 half steps) lower
>
> 2.0 is one octave (12 half steps) higher

So if I need:

> input: 0  output: 1
>
> input:-12 output: 0.5
>
> input:12  output: 2

The equation has to be something like:

> f(x) = f(x-1) * 2

But I don't remember how to solve equations like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look-up table would be faster but here's an equation (in C#):

```
public double NormalizeScaleStep(int Input)
{
    double Note = 1.0;

    if (Input == 0)
        return Note;

    if (Input > 0)
    {
        for (int Index = 0; Index < Input; Index++)
        {
            Note = Note * 1.059463094;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int Index = Input; Index < 0; Index++)
        {
            Note = Note / 1.059463094;
        }
    }

    return Note;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  This equation was also worked out for me: f(x) = ((x^2) / 576) + (x/16) + 1

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, why not just do something like Note * pow(1.059463094, n)?

Comment: Or `Note * pow(2, Input / 12.0)`